# iOS App with Static Lib crashes ONLY on launch of Archive Build loaded Ad Hoc. Can't reproduce in Debugger

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I realize this is a stretch and I can't give much info to help but I am reaching for anything. My App has been under continuous development for 3 years and never seen anything like this. I recently submitted a small point release to Apple for Release, and twice now it has been rejected for Crashing on Launch on ALL their devices?

The Crash reports point to some code in static library but the key lines are not getting symbolicated. Tried Atos no luck.

The key point is that I have 7 devices I have tested the app on in every mode I can think of, in particular no connection to anything: Wifi-OFF, AirplaneMode-ON, Location services-OFF. I can NEVER simulate what they claim to be seeing, which is App crashes on launch every time?!

I found one report in the AAPL Dev Forums that sounded similar, but he never got any explanation as to what was up. After he submitted an app with loads of logging in it out of desperation and asked them to send the logs. They got that version and... approved it in hours.

Anyone have ANY ideas.  I NEED to get this release out.

---

NOTE: Resolved

---

This turned out to NOT be a weak link issue. We only saw the crash when running the App using Ad Hoc distribution of the Archive version as Brad suggested... so that was helpful.

However the resolution turned out to be some compiler flags which I listed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302012/754494

Comment: What they have is not what you're testing?

Comment: Are you suggesting trying an adhoc build? Didn't do that yet, but what I tested was definitely what they had.

Comment: Are you testing with a release (debug off) build ?

Comment: Can you put the crash report to a site like pastebin.com or similar?

Comment: Try building and archiving the application, then choosing to distribute it for ad hoc or enterprise description. Take the .ipa and place it in iTunes and manually load it on one of your test devices that way. I just ran into a very subtle weak linking bug that was not showing when installing via Xcode, but did expose itself when manually loading an .ipa package in iTunes. It also involved a static library within the project, and would have also shown up in distribution builds submitted for review.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll repost and expand upon my comment from above so that this question can have an accepted answer.

I recently came across a case similar to this when building my GPUImage framework. It appears that the build process is slightly different when archiving than when building and directly installing an application on the device via Xcode.

This can be exposed by building and archiving the application, then choosing to distribute it for ad hoc or enterprise distribution. Take the .ipa and place it in iTunes and manually load it on one of your test devices that way. The behavior of an application prepared in this manner may differ from one built and installed through Xcode, and should be closer to how a build submitted for review will act.

In my case, the problem was due to a lack of proper weak linking. On SDKs newer than iOS 4.3, you should no longer need to weak link whole frameworks if you wish to conditionally use classes and functions that are present in newer SDKs but missing in older ones. If you target 4.0 and higher, the linker should now perform class- and function-level weak linking.

However, this was failing for people using my static library, which does runtime checks for the presence of the new texture cache functions in iOS 5.0, but it only failed in these archived builds. I never saw it in all my testing against 4.x devices, because that was done by installing via Xcode. In the end, I needed to have users explicitly weak link the entire Core Video framework in order to get applications using this framework to run properly when archived and installed via iTunes.

Note that this wasn't due to the Release vs. Debug build configurations, because I tried switching between these in my build schemes when deploying to the device through Xcode and it made no difference there. Something else is different in the way that archived applications are built and linked.