# iOS App with Static Lib ALWAYS crashes on Launch of Ad Hoc Archive Build. Cant reproduce in Xcode Debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

We have an App built with a static Lib we are also building for distribution. The App and Lib run fine in Xcode debugger or when loaded on the device by Xcode debugging session. The App ALWAYS crashes as soon as we put an Ad Hoc Archive build on the device. Console log statements indicate it is crashing in Lib code, but crash report not symbolicating Lib code.

- Can't reproduce in Xcode Simulator.
- Guard malloc, Guard Edges show nothing (but these only run in simulator).
- No leaks
- Using Xcode 4.3.2
- App targets 4.3 or later.
- Lib targets 3.0 or later.
- Other Linker Flags = -ObjC
- Lib set as "Optional" in Target "Link Binaries With Libraries"
- Thumb support off (using LLVM)

Seeing 2 exceptions on console that might be of use, but so far not turning anything up on net that helps much with this:

```
Application 'x' exited abnormally with signal 12: Bad system call: 12 (mostly)
Application 'x' exited abnormally with signal 12: Bad system call: 11 (rarely)
```

We saw the comment elsewhere that static libs with Recursion have issues. But we don't had any recursion in our Lib.

Stumped, need more ideas.

Comment: What about not AdHoc but Debug tests on real device? Is it reproducible then? I just ask to rule out the possibility of build differences in the targets.

Comment: Didn't try that but all the logging statements pointed to a block of serialization code that we thought might have a buffer overrun. Nope. It is very, very, very. Odd.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Figured it out!!** after 4 days of banging heads on desk. We don't know exactly why it works but it does. In case it's helpful to others here are the settings that resolved it for us. Set these in the "Deployment" section of the Static Library Project's Build Settings:

```
SET "STRIP LINKED PRODUCT" (STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT) = NO
SET "STRIP STYLE" = DEBUGGING SYMBOLS.
```

We found this by trial and error but now notice that a few discussions online re setting up an Xcode project for building iOS static libraries use this setting. No discussion as to why, but there it is.

If anyone has any thoughts on why these lib settings fix it you might want to comment on it here.

Comment: NOTE: I did go into Apple Developer Forum and specifically ask WHY DOES THIS WORK, and WHY DO WE HAVE TO DO THIS. No response thus far. Not a peep! Im betting theres a bug in there somewhere. If the compiler needs Symbols for a Lib, it should throw some warning or exception at compile time and not just crash!

Comment: At WWDC I did ask a Linker GURU about this. He said this is one way to  do it. But suggested another approach to building the library where Symbols CAN be stripped. Will post another note when we fully work that out.

Comment: Had a similar problem - libdispatch was crashing when calling back to one of my blocks. The block was in a statically linked pseudo-framework. Changing the linker flags as mentioned above seems to have fixed this problem (in fact the only flag I changed was the STRIP STYLE one - the other one was already set to NO).

Comment: We had the same problem with our IPA and this "fix" worked for us [applied to static lib project]. @CliffRibaudo any update on your "alternate approach"?

Comment: Didn't get around to trying it. But I did note that the latest version of Xcode now throws a fatal exception if you try to compile with Strip Linked Product set to YES.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I had the same problem a while back and this post saved me from madness.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I posted it in case anyone was still having a Ad Hoc build issue after trying this approach. I tried this fix but it didn't work however the question I linked helped me but was hard to find.

Comment: Well then use the Bookmark or favorites feature of StackOverflow to save the question for later use. It is more efficient and doesn't confuse others.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and tried changing the project build settings, but it didn't work for me. Eventually solved my problem by changing the compiler optimization level setting for the release:

In Build Settings, go to the LLVM compiler 4.2 - Code Generation section, look for the Optimization Level option and change the Release setting from Fastest, Smallest [-Os] to None [-O0].

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The chance is very high that your build settings are different between AdHoc (Release) and Debug.
Did you double-check all build-settings values?
Especially look at the ARC (automatic reference counting) settings.

Comment: In my case, the crash occurred when running a release build installed via Ad-Hoc distribution, but not when running a release build installed and launched via Xcode. Note that both were release builds. The ad-hoc build was created as part of the archiving process, so it wasn't technically the same binary file as the release build, but it was built with the same target settings, and identical code, which seems to imply that it's something going on in the archiving/re-signing/ad-hoc-installation process which is making the difference.

Comment: Sam, nope. This issue is related to the way the linker works, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Debug, by loading with the Xcode debugger, your Production build (probably set to Release Build with very different optimization and code gen settings than the Debug build you are currently testing with).

Comment: Tried that. Running that way crashed in the same place and told us nothing.