# iOS Application Will not Launch From Adhoc Distribution Because It can't find XCTest Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution, xctest

I made a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261753/ios-app-wont-start-on-testflight-ad-hoc-distribution) before about this problem, but since then I've been able to find some crash logs on some testers' devices.

Interestingly the count of crash logs on the device do not match the number of crashes, but still, this may be a clue.

Long story short, when I distribute my application to testers via TestFlight, then can't open the app: it closes before anything can happen (I know this because there are no TestFlight crash logs). All the on-device logs I've managed to find point to the same problem:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000120085098
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/36942309-D734-4003-8971-97C0CF047BFC/XYZ.app/XYZ
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 324.1

Binary Images:
0x120084000 - 0x1200abfff dyld arm64  <628da833271c3f9bb8d44c34060f55e0> /usr/lib/dyld
0x182560000 - 0x1826bffff CoreGraphics arm64  <c16c7faf626234f1992f1e7f27ef992f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x182f68000 - 0x1831a7fff Foundation arm64  <a698ba21ece734889c74bf2c20e6aea4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x184138000 - 0x1841b3fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <21036a78054f3e3b8d018be04c3b6bf4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x185084000 - 0x1851fffff QuartzCore arm64  <1ae8ea71790d382e84c3d403f0afaffd> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x185264000 - 0x1852bbfff Security arm64  <b27dccf33c573663b07cdbf5d3c9a797> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x185428000 - 0x18548ffff SystemConfiguration arm64  <58592ccb97af3ceb9008b388c1692d0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x185494000 - 0x185ccbfff UIKit arm64  <434cd368625b376d86dd6c672552efe1> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18ef44000 - 0x18ef57fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <070746af9ba53c1ca2d1bf0d2067fb80> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

How in the world a breakpoint is getting triggered on a release build, I have no idea. I can't reproduce this while running the app from Xcode. I have removed XCTest framework from Xcode's 'Link Binary with Libraries' list. But it hasn't helped yet.

Has anyone come across a similar issue before?

**UPDATE**:

Someone has mentioned in the comments that this question may be a duplicate. I just want to point out that in the question linked, the OP has a stack trace, whereas in my case, the app is not launching at all and there is no trace in the logs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are "EXC\_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)" exceptions caused by debugging breakpoints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611607/are-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap-exceptions-caused-by-debugging-breakpoints)

Comment: These questions are similar but not duplicates - although I hadn't seen that one and it does tell me what not to worry about. In my case, the app is not launching, whereas the other poster has a stack trace. I've included more the logs to indicate this.

Comment: Did you ever find a reasonable way of solving this. Having exactly the same issue. Looking at CocoaPods and XCAsyncTestCase issues.

Comment: @Giles: I feel your pain... [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300800/ios-app-with-static-lib-always-crashes-on-launch-of-ad-hoc-archive-build-cant-r/10302012#comment38038783_10302012)'s solution is what helped me. Still don't quite understand why it worked, but haven't had the problem since making those build setting changes.

Comment: Thank you Shinigami. We got there in the end. We were incorrectly adding XCAsyncTestCase to our target with Cocoapods. This was linking to XCTest. It looks as though XCTest is temporarily pushed onto iOS devices when they are plugged into a developer Mac. This meant that a distribution build worked on phones that had been plugged into a Mac set up for development. If you then restarted that phone the app stopped working. This confused us somewhat!

Comment: Makes sense... we had the exact same problem. We'd plug the crashing devices in and that would magically make things work. I don't think we were doing anything funky with cocoapods tho, so that's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create new project in Xcode5, and copy all files to new project.