# App crashes in ad hoc archive but not when built from IDE

Tags: ios, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to distribute my app on Testflight but it's crashing for everyone. Works fine when I build from XCode directly onto the device.

The app worked fine on Testflight about a week ago, but a bunch of changes were made.

Here's the crash log:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x30fbaecb __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b751ce7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30fbae0d +[NSException raise:format:] + 112
3   Lexly                           0x0022e0af 0x101000 + 1233071
4   Lexly                           0x0021ac21 0x101000 + 1154081
5   Lexly                           0x002212ad 0x101000 + 1180333
6   Lexly                           0x00221f23 0x101000 + 1183523
7   Lexly                           0x001659ad 0x101000 + 412077
8   Lexly                           0x0015d7ed 0x101000 + 378861
9   Lexly                           0x0015d587 0x101000 + 378247
10  Lexly                           0x0015d4d7 0x101000 + 378071
11  Lexly                           0x00130d69 0x101000 + 195945
12  Lexly                           0x00130d19 0x101000 + 195865
13  UIKit                           0x33806d03 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 438
14  CoreFoundation                  0x30f03aa3 __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 50
15  CoreFoundation                  0x30efd4bd -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 220
16  UIKit                           0x33806e49 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 764
17  UIKit                           0x3386be5f -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 54
18  UIKit                           0x3386bde9 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316
19  UIKit                           0x337e4b53 _afterCACommitHandler + 458
20  CoreFoundation                  0x30f85ff9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
21  CoreFoundation                  0x30f83987 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 286
22  CoreFoundation                  0x30f83cd3 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
23  CoreFoundation                  0x30eee729 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
24  CoreFoundation                  0x30eee50b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
25  GraphicsServices                0x35e4d6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
26  UIKit                           0x3384f871 UIApplicationMain + 1136
27  Lexly                           0x0013084f 0x101000 + 194639
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x3bc4fab7 start + 2


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3bd061f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3bd6e7b3 pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3bcb6ff5 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b10598b abort_message + 71
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b11e6e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b751f7b _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b11c1b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3b11bd13 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b751e2b objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30eee79b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30eee507 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices                0x35e4d6cf GSEventRunModal + 135
12  UIKit                           0x3384f86d UIApplicationMain + 1133
13  Lexly                           0x0013084b 0x101000 + 194635
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3bc4fab5 start + 1
```

I tried the fix in this SO question but no luck:

[iOS App with Static Lib ALWAYS crashes on Launch of Ad Hoc Archive Build. Cant reproduce in Xcode Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300800/ios-app-with-static-lib-always-crashes-on-launch-of-ad-hoc-archive-build-cant-r/10302012#10302012)

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log so you can the exact line of code causing the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I got that crash report from "Devices > View Device Logs" in Xcode. How do I symbolicate this report? The report is pulled from the device into Xcode.