# My application is performing differenet when it's processing to apple store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

This is really really a weird case .. I have an application which is works perfectly with my devices , we have tested it many times .. so after apple review and approved it , it has been published on apple store .. I download the version on apple store and its performing different to the one I have on my code .. i will describe it through screen shot , We'v built a custom control with a dragging ball when you drag it a menu with buttons will appear like this pic

[image]

But the disaster is when I download the app from apple store is performing like this

[image]

So As you can see the ball is not in the correct position beside that the menu is disappearing some times .. Im really sure that the code I'v upload it to the iTunes is EXACTLY same the one I'm testing on my devices (svn history log also can prove that to me) .. please notice that my app have been approved today I don't know if it has any relation with that problem.

Please I need your help !!

Note : this is happened on both iPhone and iPad and in all iOS versions.

Comment: Try and get a copy of your code onto a fresh dev machine and deploy to a fresh device to see if you can replicate what is shown in the App Store file.

Comment: is your phone or iPad jailbroken?

Comment: @SuhailPatel i don't think will solve any thing since all the team is try it.

Comment: @Eric no .. non of the devices is jalibroken.

Comment: Upload the latest build again and it will take less time for review.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore but why do I need to upload it again with the same code !!! what may cause this to happened ?

Comment: Which profile are you using? Maybe there are differences between Debug and Release -- in a library or in a chunk of code.

Comment: @Panagiotis I'v tried them both .. debug mode and release mode (using add hoc).

Comment: Hmm check your info.plist and clean up your build directory and see again. Also do a reset on your iphone / ipad (either it is emulator or physical). There could be residues of graphics (or non changed graphics) that are not being replaced. Are the images from the main bundle?

Comment: yes the images is from the main bundle .. but i don't think its a graphic issue the ball position is a calculation done in the code. and btw i tried that .. no difference :(

Comment: Test this with an archive build that you manually load onto your device via iTunes, instead of testing your application through Xcode. As I point out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10265140/19679 there appears to be a slight difference in the way that archived and App Store builds are linked, so you could test and see if this issue appears in non-Xcode-installed builds.

Comment: Have you used the same scheme as the one you send to app store when you test the app?

Comment: @BradLarson post it as an answer please so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brad Larson Said : I found that the problem is happened when I archive the app in xcode .. I just archive it again and upload it and everything is working normal now without change anything in the code !

Answer (score 2):

A little-known fact is that you can install App Store builds<sup>*</sup> on device. I've just tested this on iOS 5.1 to make sure it still works. Just unzip the .zip you uploaded and drag MyApp.app to the Applications list in the Xcode organizer.

The only requirement is that you have a "matching" profile installed on device. I have not worked out what profiles are matched on, but it should work if *everything* is identical except for the profile name<sup>**</sup>, device list, and App Store/Ad Hoc setting.

(Presumably this is designed to let you add a device to a provisioning profile and install the app without rebuilding/re-signing it. An App Store profile is simply an Ad Hoc profile without a UDID list.)

Alternatively, you can re-sign the build with `codesign -f --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules,requirements` assuming the profiles are sufficiently similar that they can use the same entitlements.

<sup>*</sup> Those whose `embedded.mobileprovision` file is an "App Store" profile.
<sup>**</sup> I usually use "MyApp AppStore" and "MyApp AdHoc", but your company may have different conventions.

Comment: I used the Xcode to upload the binary not the application loader , so I don't have the zip file !

Comment: +1 oh I could access the .app from archives in the Xcode .. your answer helped me some way ,, thank you ,, but at the end I have to upload a new binary.